# Teamcity: How to reset an agent to a previous state

Tags: teamcity

I have a test running on my Windows Agent. During the execution of test extra Software gets installed like an SQL-Server and drivers. After the test execution I would like to reset the state of  the agent so that everything is clean and nothing is installed, like with snapshots in VMWare. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you should try Docker for Windows and run your tests inside a container

Comment: Teamcity doesn't support this type of cleanup no. You need to use other tools in the DevOps toolbox for this, like containers or even a thin provisioned VM